# Update Azure Synced Sql Table is Slow

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I have synced an on premise SQL Table to Azure (one direction) and added a Bit column on the Azure table. There are over 500K rows.

While updating the Bit column in Azure, the update query seems to take too long.

The database service tier is set to Standard with 10 DTU

What could be the reason for slow performance?

Comment: hard to say without more details - is the database on an appropriate tier for usage, are your indexes suitable for the update, etc.

Comment: From http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net .... I need to find the parameters for a query plan to determine the required DTU ...is there a way to retrieve them through management studio?